# How to monitor scripts executed via cron and perform action on elapsed times?

Tags: linux, bash, cron, scripting, shell

I run numerous scripts via CRON throughout the day, and as they rely on third-party providers which sometimes are slow, I currently run them like so `timeout 60m bash /script.sh` and that's worked great for me. Terminate the script after 60 minutes, as it should only take 5 minutes to run, etc.

I do log the job and output to log files when certain parts of the scripts are executed, but I'm looking to get a little more verbose as to what's going on with my scripts and jobs. I'm looking for a way to notify me, as an example, every 10 minutes of execution (a running timer would be needed of course). I don't need to know how to notify me or anything I can handle that, but I am looking for input as to "how" I can monitor the various scripts notifying me every X minutes (different for different scripts), as well as notifying me when the script would be killed even.

I did try various things with `ps` but unless I'm doing something extremely weird with my jobs, I get 3 results for every script that's executed.

Example CRON entry:

`42 01 * * *  mkdir -p '/tmp-data/logs/specific-script/' && timeout 60m bash /script.sh > /tmp-data/logs/specific-script-$(date ...)`

Using something like `ps -e -o pid,etime,etimes,cmd | grep '[b]ash'`

I get three entries per CRON job it seems, and of course all 3 don't need to be killed, so I wouldn't even know how to find the "one" that does...

```
/bin/sh -c timeout 60m bash /script.sh ...
timeout 60m bash /script.sh ...
bash /script.sh ...
```

Not looking for code really, any direction even as to how others "monitor" their jobs and keep tabs on how long they are running, executing commands if they run slow/long and killing ones that run too long and getting notified it was killed.

Answer (score 1):

I've moved most of my cron jobs into systemd timer units. This makes the process of managing them much easier; I don't need to use `ps` to look up processes to see what to PID to kill.

E.g, instead of:

```
42 01 * * *  mkdir -p '/tmp-data/logs/specific-script/' && timeout 60m bash /script.sh > /tmp-data/logs/specific-script-$(date ...)
```

I would create a [service](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html) in `~/.config/systemd/user/myservice.service`:

```
[Service]
RuntimeMaxSec=60m
ExecStart=/bin/bash /script.sh
```

And then a [timer](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.timer.html) in `~/.config/systemd/user/myservice.timer`:

```
[Timer]
OnCalendar=01:42:00

[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

And then:

```
$ systemctl --user enable myservice.timer
```

Now:

- I can rely on systemd to collect the logs, which I can see by running `journalctl --user -u myservice`. There are a variety of additional flags I can pass to `journalctl` to filter messages by time, content, etc.
- Rather than using `timeout`, I'm letting systemd manage the maximum service runtime.
- If I need to stop a service prematurely, I can simply run `systemctl --user stop myservice`; no need to look things up with `ps`.
- If I want to stop the service from running periodically, I can `systemctl --user stop myservice.timer` (to stop the timer until next reboot), or `systemctl --user disable --now myservice.timer` (to both stop the timer and prevent it from starting again after the next reboot).
- If I want to run the service on demand, I can `systemctl --user start myservice`.

---

With respect to monitoring your services, you could probably handle that with an `ExecStopPost` script in your service unit. These scripts have access to a [number of environment variables](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#Environment%20Variables%20Set%20or%20Propagated%20by%20the%20Service%20Manager), including `$SERVICE_RESULT`.

If your service is killed because it exceeded `RuntimeMaxSec`, `$SERVICE_RESULT` will be `timeout`, so you could check this and perform some monitoring action (send an email, play a sound, whatever).

```
[Service]
RuntimeMaxSec=60m
ExecStart=/bin/bash /script.sh
ExecStopPost=/bin/bash /script-to-check-and-notify-me.sh
```

The timeout will also be part of the service log, e.g:

```
$ journalctl --user -u exampleservice
Aug 28 07:59:44 madhatter systemd[5559]: Started exampleservice.service.
Aug 28 07:59:54 madhatter systemd[5559]: exampleservice.service: Service reached runtime time limit. Sto>
Aug 28 07:59:54 madhatter systemd[5559]: exampleservice.service: Failed with result 'timeout'.
```

Comment: Hmm, this would remove the need for ~50 CRON's, but I would have ~50 services (not a big deal to me technically), but how could/would I still do things like notify myself every X minutes/hours of the service running when things are delayed, how would I notify myself when the RuntimeMaxSec was reached and it kills the service? *Unless services can inherently handle this, in which case I apologize. Just to confirm though, I would ultimately need a service and timer for every current CRON entry, correct?

Comment: I've added an update the hopefully addresses most of those questions. Yes, you would a timer + service for each cron entry.